# What is the difference between log on and log on xorg?

Tags: xorg, log

Ubuntu 17.10 is installed in my laptop.

I selected log on xorg when log in.

And I don't see an differences compare with log on.

What is the difference between log on and log on xorg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're running Ubuntu 17.10 (please edit your questions to include the version of Ubuntu that you're running to make it easier for us to help troubleshoot your issue), the options that you're describing are for the types of [display servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) that Ubuntu will use when you log in.

[X.Org (or just Xorg)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) is an older display server that recently has been replaced by [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))--and made the default--as of Ubuntu 17.10. However, because there are still applications that depend on X.Org, the option to use this older display server is still made available to you.

In general, using Wayland (just the "log on" option you describe) should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many apps like *SimpleScreenRecorder* will demand you to use **Xorg** login. Xorg is also famous in many tools that can help you stablish a remote connection to a server/PC.

All in all, it is a capability, so use it to shoot your last bullet when you face difficulties in terms of Display or VGA issues like the app I mentioned above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).